# Add font family in resourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resources

I am using the [msdn tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) to add a FontFamily in my Wpf application, in .csproj I have :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\MetaOT-Norm.otf" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\MetaOT-Bold.otf" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I added the fontfamily in the ResourceDictionary, like that :

```
<FontFamily x:Key="FontMetaOT">./Resources/#Meta OT</FontFamily>
```

But it's not applied... (I have tried with the Font files in the windows Fonts directory and it's work well). Any idea ?

Comment: Is it a problem with OpenType fonts?

Comment: @ahmet what do you mean ? Effectivly I didn't found any sample using  .otf extension, most of them use a .ttf extension... Do you think I can use .otf extension with this code ?

Comment: Silverlight Supports OTF.  Have you tried a direct reference? Like this: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/09/25/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-46-font-support-in-silverlight.aspx

Comment: The problem is the Uri isn't resolved... If I try ../Resources/#Meta OT it's work well

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a resource dictionary file, you have to address the files using the [Pack URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx).
For instance:

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that
>   is located in the root of the referenced assembly's project folder.

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml
```

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that
>   is located in a subfolder of the referenced assembly's project folder.

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml
```

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that
>   is located in the root folder of a referenced, version-specific
>   assembly's project folder.

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1;component/ResourceFile.xaml
```

If the file is located in the output folder, you can use site of origin to refer to it:

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML site of origin
>   file, stored in the location from which the executable assembly is
>   launched.

```
pack://siteoforigin:,,,/SiteOfOriginFile.xaml
```

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML site of origin
>   file, stored in subfolder that is relative to the location from which
>   the application's executable assembly is launched.

```
pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Subfolder/SiteOfOriginFile.xaml
```

As an example:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--A resource dictionary in the output folder in the Assets folder-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Assets/OpenIconsDictionary.xaml"/>
            <!--A resource dictionary packed in the Gui dll-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Gui;component/Assets/PackedIconsDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>



<!--In the output folder /Assets/OpenIconsDictionary.xaml (Build Action: Embedded Resource, Copy always)-->
<ResourceDictionary
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon"                 
                 UriSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/image.png"/>


</ResourceDictionary>


<!--In Gui.dll in the folder /Assets/PackedIconsDictionary.xaml (Build Action: Page, Do not copy)-->
<ResourceDictionary
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon"                 
                 UriSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/image.png"/>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: but where do I have to use this, inside FontFamily Tag or inside Resource, would be nice to see a full example.