# Change default font family to own font file group in Windows 8.1 Xaml Store App

Tags: xaml, fonts, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have an own font as files in the project and do an overwrite of the default fontfamily key in the globalstyle.xaml (like described in the post [Change global application font in a Windows 8.1 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150457/change-global-application-font-in-a-windows-8-1-app)):

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">/Assets/Fonts/myFontType-Roman.ttf#myFont Type</FontFamily>
```

This works like a charm - for one font file.

My question:
Is it possible to have a font Family Group references in the style instead of just one file somehow?
The only possiblity I found is for WPF and seems not to work in WinRT ([Add font family in resourceDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706489/add-font-family-in-resourcedictionary))

I have four font files (myFontType-Bold.ttf, myFontType-Light.ttf, myFontType-Italic.ttf and myFontType-Roman.ttf), which are one font Family group, when locally installed on the System. But the font should not be installed on the System.

One idea was to define four keys and add all four fontfamilies. But this is not an Option, since we want to use the different font weight through the keyword fontweight in the style and not by reference different font families.

Any ideas or correct ways to Group These files into one Group and overwrite the "ContentControlThemeFontFamily" key to apply the fontFamily to the whole app.

Thank you for any ideas.

**Edit:**
By the way, I tried also to only use the font Family Name:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">/Assets/Fonts/#myFont Type</FontFamily>
```

But this seems to have no effect...

Comment: Try it without the leading `/`.

Comment: thanks. but this does not work. You can test it yourself: with the leading `/`,  `<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">/Assets/Fonts/myFontType-Roman.ttf#myFont Type</FontFamily>`, the custom font will be used. if the slash is removed, the system default font is used...

Answer (score 1):

You can change font family by simply using attribute i.e (FontFamily).
Code must look like this :-

```
   <TextBlock Content="Meal-" Foreground="Black"  FontFamily="Assets/Font/MixBrush.ttf#MixBrush"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="55" />
```

Here **Assets/Font/MixBrush.ttf#MixBrush** is located in manifest file.
Thanks & Regards,